# Using a struct exported from IDA with pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, struct, ida

So I have exported a struct from IDA Pro and put it in a header file like so:

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct CPed
{
     float health;
     CPed *closestPeds[10];
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

In the main I used it like this:

```
unsigned int ClosestPed = *(unsigned int *)(*(unsigned int *)PlayerPointer + NearestPeds);
CPed *nearestPed = (CPed *)ClosestPed;
nearestPed->health = 0;
```

As I see it, the first line of code in the main should add the `NearestPeds` offset to the `PlayerPointer` and put it into `ClosestPed`.

Now `ClosestPed` holds the address of the closest ped.

Now I pass that address into `*nearestPed` and then finally set the closest ped's health to `0`, only, the ped's health never gets set to `0`. It never dies.

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong?

Comment: What `PlayerPointer` and `NearestPeds` are?

Comment: `PlayerPointer` is: `0x94AD28` - This points to the Player.
`NearestPeds` is an offset of `PlayerPointer`: `0x56C` - This collects the 10 closest peds.

Comment: And what their types are?

Comment: `PlayerPointer` is of type `[Pointer]`.
`NearestPeds` is of type `[10 Pointers]`.

Comment: Great. Pointers to what? Give full definition of the type. And how can be offset of type `10 pointers`?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
CPed* nearestPed = (CPed*)(*(PlayerPointer+9));
nearestPed->health = 0;
```